# Comparing numbers wrong

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS which compares credit card number length:

```
validate: function () {
    var ccLength = $('.credit-card input[name="cc_number"]').val().length;
    var cardType = parseInt($('.credit-card .credit-card-type .selected').attr('rel'));
    if (!isNaN(cardType)) {
        console.log(ccLength); //11
        console.log(provider[cardType].validLength.split(',')); // ["16", "13"]

        if (ccLength == 0 || (cardType > 0 && (ccLength < parseInt(provider[cardType].validLength)) || (!$.inArray(ccLength, provider[cardType].validLength.split(','))))) {
            triggerNotification('x', 'Your credit card number isn\'t long enough');
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($('.credit-card input[name="cc_cvv"]').val().length < 3) {
                triggerNotification('x', 'You must provide a CCV');
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        triggerNotification('x', 'Credit card type is not recognized or accepted');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
```

I've included the values of console.log() on the 5th & 6th lines.  For some reason, it doesn't fail...

**update**

`provider[cardType].validLength` is always either `'16,13'` or `'16'`

Comment: can you provide sample input that is being validated?  and why you think it should be failing

Comment: The example input is included in the comment after console.log()

Comment: What's `(ccLength < provider[cardType].validLength) ` intended to do? it's comparing a number against a string containing a comma-separated list of numbers, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Webnet, the value of cardType hasn't been provided

Comment: And && has higher precedence than || so your condition isn't quite what was intended, although that doesn't explain your issue. It's equivalent to ` ((ccLength == 0 || ((cardType > 0 &&   (ccLength < provider[cardType].validLength)) ||   (!$.inArray(ccLength, provider[cardType].validLength.split(',')))))` (extra parens around the `cardType > 0 && ccLength < provider[cardType].validLength`

Comment: is cardType realy an Integer? Otherwise cardType > 0 evaluates to false

Comment: @scheffield, it's the return value from parseInt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.inArray( 16, ['16'] ); //=>-1
```